# DDD Custom properties by dynamic composition of a document/entity

Tags: domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

We're refactoring our solution to a Domain Driven Design structure. Our consultants which implement the software, should be able to customize some behavior of the application (for specific customers needs). For example they want to add custom defined properties to the presentation (user input forms) and save the custom data together with the entities defined in our DDD projects.

However, the domain objects should preferably not contain a customData property. I don't want to mix those and let the domain object know that there's something like custom data. I'm saving en fetching the entities by Repositories.

How do I make this scenario possible? One possible solution would be:

- Query the entity by using his Repository
- And query separately the CustomPropertiesRepository by entity ID.
- Combine the two queries objects.
- When saving the forms. It will be splitted again using two repositories

The disadvantage of this, is that I have to query twice though it should be one document.

Any advice on this problem?

Comment: "However, I don't want the domain objects have the knowledge that there are custom properties" What do you mean?

Comment: Changed the description to make it more clear.

Comment: Maybe I should use some form of projections to make a single view of those 2 (domain en custom data) combined...

Comment: "The disadvantage of this, is that I have to query twice though it should be one document." I don't see it as a problem

Comment: "some form of projections " Are you using CQRS?

Comment: No i'm just using DDD

Comment: "However, the domain objects should preferably not contain a customData property" But why ?

Comment: @KeesSchouten Your problem is too abstract. It doesn't speak of the business at all. What business problem this part of the software solves? Why do you think that these custom data fields shouldn't be modeled in the domain? Is there are invariants to enforce regarding these custom data fields?

Comment: mmm it seems that these "custom properties" are part of your domain.
Why you don't like to have a value object `CustomProperties` wrapping a map in your Entity?

Comment: Who is the user of your software? Do you explicitly use term "custom property" while discussing the problem with them? If yes, then the "custom property" is probably your domain concept and therefore should be included in your model. Otherwise, it seems this design is smelly and should be avoided. Please, try to add some examples.

Answer (score 0):

in general dynamic properties are better suited for data-centric design and in my opinion this practice is not suitable for DDD.

in DDD the code must reflect the knowledge of the domain, it must be simple and explicit.

before thinking of the best way to persist a dynamic property, you must solve the problem at the design level:
1-There are three possible artifacts for a property: aggregate root, entity or object value.

2-usually a dynamic property brings with it a functional need (calculation, validation ... etc), where you will implement this functionality? whether in the aggregate root or in a domain service you will be compelled to compile your code and here the dynamic propriety loses its meaning, unless you think use a Business rules engine, and there you introduce another new paradigm with its whole complication, and some of your business logic would be outside aggregates and domain services.